# Splitting a command line argument in C

Tags: c, split, command-line-arguments

I want to split the first command line argument into two different numbers. I got a segmentation fault error when running the program this way:

```
gcc -ansi main.c -o main
./main 6000V7000
```

Here is the source code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char *token;
    char arr[200];
    strcpy(arr, argv[1]);

    token = strtok(arr, "v,V");
    int firstNumber = atoi(token);
    token = strtok(NULL, "v,V");
    int secondNumber = atoi(token);

    return 0;
}
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: I don't get a segmentation fault error.

Comment: This code works fine, as it should. If it doesn't for you, then you have not included enough detail in the question.

Comment: Are you sure this is the same code that is generating the error, or did you "simplify" it and remove the error in the process?  It will fail if the input _does not_ contain a delimiter.  You should test `strtok` return for NULL before attempting `atoi()`.  Run it in GDB - it will tell you exactly which line the fault occurs and the parameters to any function call involved - and you can inspect any other variables.

Comment: Compile with `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`. And read [how to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: @choptxen: you can accept one of the answers by clicking on the grey checkmark below its score.

Answer (score 3):

You do not test if there is at least one command line argument, nor that this argument is less than 200 characters long, nor do you test the return values of `strtok`: you would have undefined behavior if the command is given no argument or if the argument does not contain any of the characters `v`, `V` or `,`.

If you effectively compile the program with `gcc -ansi main.c -o main` and run it with the posted argument as `./main 6000V7000` you should not get a segmentation fault... There is something you are not telling us ;)

It is always better to avoid wild assumptions: test for the unexpected to give your program defined behavior in all cases.

Here is a simpler approach for your problem using `sscanf()`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int a, b;
    if (argc > 1 && sscanf(argv[1], "%d%*1[vV,]%d", &a, &b) == 2)
        printf("a=%d, b=%d\n", a, b);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Good solution - no buffer required.

Answer (score 1):

The code and command line arguments given do not seg-fault.  However if the command line argument either omits the delimiter, includes a space before the second number, or omits any argument at all, then it will fail.

The following will prevent erroneous input causing a runtime error:

```
if( argc > 1 )
{
    strcpy( arr, argv[1]);

    int firstNumber = 0 ;
    int secondNumber = 0 ;
    token = strtok(arr, "v,V");
    if( token != NULL )
    {
        firstNumber = atoi(token) ;
        token = strtok(NULL, "v,V") ;
        if( token != NULL )
        {
            secondNumber= atoi(token); 
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

There's only one `"V"` in your input. The second call to `strtok()` finds no V and returns `NULL`.

Comment: The *first* call to `strtok` returns a pointer to `6000`. The *second* call to `strtok` returns a pointer to `7000`.

Comment: That is not how strtok works.  It would return NULL on the third call.

Answer (score -1):

You must define var at the begin of the function :

The follow `code` could work :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    char *token;
    char arr[200];
    int firstNumber;
    int secondNumber;

    strcpy( arr, argv[1]);

    token = strtok(arr, "v,V");
    firstNumber = atoi(token);
    token = strtok(NULL, "v,V");
    secondNumber= atoi(token);

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Not since C99 you don't.  And that would not cause a seg-fault in any case.

Comment: Agree with you; that said, he seems to use C ansi (see compile line)

Comment: GCC doc:  _"The -ansi option does not cause non-ISO programs to be rejected gratuitously. For that, -Wpedantic is required in addition to -ansi."_. It is academic - this is still not an answer to the question of why it seg-faults.

Comment: @Clifford Can you give me a link about the doc?

Comment: The GNU GCC documentation is easy to find:  https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-8.2.0/gcc/C-Dialect-Options.html#C-Dialect-Options.  I am not saying that this is why the code is accepted when `-ansi` is used - I think the use of -ansi may have changed over different versions of GCC.  The point is however that the compiler either _did_ accept this code or the build command in the question is not the one actually used to compile it - which is quite possible since the code and command line given also do not generate a run-time error.  The point stands that this is an answer to a different question